# WP7 number of Push Notification channels limit

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

In Microsoft documentation it is mentioned that "There is a limit of one push notification channel per application. There is also a limit of 15 push notification channels per device. If your application exceeds either of these limits, an InvalidOperationException(Channel quota exceeded) exception will be thrown.".

I understand this as If the user has already installed 15 apps that use push notifications and if he installs my app which also uses push notifications as 16th one, then InvalidOperationException(Channel quota exceeded) will be thrown.

But I have no idea where we have to catch this exception in the code. Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link gives alot of information about using the pushnotifications. 
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/05/06/using-push-notification-from-your-windows-phone-application.aspx

I think you need to catch the exception when trying to create the channel.